# Android + Stripe = Performing Idempotent Charge Requests?

Tags: android, stripe-payments

I am attempting to integrate Stripe payments into my Android application, and so far things are going well - however - I noticed in the Stripe docs that they have a concept of [Idempotent requests](https://stripe.com/docs/api/java#idempotent_requests) (essentially making sure the user won't be charged twice).

The Java code example uses a `RequestOptions` object, however, this object does not appear to be given to me in the Android SDK, and the Charge.create constructors available to me do not allow for such an object to be passed along.

So my question - is there a way I can perform Idempotent requests in Android? This seems pretty important given the possibility of retrying requests due to network connectivity issues.

For note, I am using gradle to include the Stripe SDK:

```
compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:+'
```

Answer (score 1):

You should only be generating tokens from Stripe-Android. These tokens represent the card but do not actually generate any charges. This is because creating a charge in Stripe requires your secret key and you don't want to publish that.

You would then take the token and send that to your server. Your server could then include the idempotency key in its request to Stripe.

You may wish to have some idempotency system with your app and your server but that would be out of the scope of Stripe.

Comment: Interesting, I had been told that there was a way to go about integration that did not involve server side interaction - which is what I have been asked to do. I don't have immediate control over the client's server, but I will bring the question back to them.

Comment: @ssawchenko -- you should always run the tokens through your server because you need your secret key to make charges, and secret keys should never be included in Android Applications, because it can be extracted and then used to make purchases or refunds on your behalf.